# Open screen and run some projects and applications

Tags: 14.04, gnome, scripts

I am a python web developer, I need to run my local 3-4 django projects in `screen` sessions and need to launch some of my applications like `skype`, `chrome`, `eclipse` and a text file `daily status.txt`.
Is there any way to write a script to launch all of them by running a shell script only?

```
   #!/bin/bash
   # 
   gnome-terminal -e "screen -dmS myapps"

   #(Attach following command to one of the screen)
   cd /var/opt/project1
   python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8001 

   #(Attach another command to one of the screen)
   cd /var/opt/project2
   python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8002

   #(Attach another command to one of the screen)
   cd /var/opt/project3
   python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8003

   #start my applications
   eclipse
   skype
   gedit "/home/myname/Desktop/daily status.txt"
   [...]
```

Can one help me to write a shell script to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
screen -S "DjangoRunservers" -d -m

#Do this if you don't want the first screen window to be blank
#screen -S "DjangoRunservers" -X stuff 'python /var/opt/project1/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8001^M'
#Note: You get ^M by hitting Ctrl-V and the Return

screen -S "DjangoRunservers" -X screen python /var/opt/project1/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8001
screen -S "DjangoRunservers" -X screen python /var/opt/project2/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8002
screen -S "DjangoRunservers" -X screen python /var/opt/project3/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8003
```

To launch python server in a detached screen.

On my Mac, to run eclipse from the terminal I have to do it like this

```
/Applications/eclipse/eclipse
```

I'm guessing it is the same with Skype too.

Comment: :Thanks for reply. But I'm looking for a script which run all the projects in single screen session. I wonder what would happen if I use a "daemon" to achieve my task.

Comment: Right, updated the answer to add the runservers in the same session.